# Respond to completion of a scheduled job

Tags: oracle, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled which runs fine, until it doesn't. When it failed it use to rollback which was the desired behavior. It still does this, but there are DDL statements in it now which are committing which has changed exactly how this happens, because it only rolls back to the last commit instead of the whole job.

I want to add the creation of a restore point to the start of the job, and then respond to the completion of the job, if it fails, it uses the restore point, if it succeeds then it deletes the restore point.

What I cant figure out is how to automatically have something respond to the completion of the job, much like a trigger responds to changes to a table for instance. I could have another task get fired off that waits for this one to complete and then do its job, but that's wasting resources and I feel its a poor solution when I'm sure there must be a better way.

No, I cant use chain jobs.

Comment: Why do you use DDL in such a way? If possible, do all DDLs *before* running a job. By the way, what kind of DDL is it?

Comment: @Littlefoot The DDL is used to turn on and off triggers because their behavior is either needed or not during the run of the scheduled job. In one case their being used to perform basic auditing of new or changed records in a table.

Comment: I see; thanks. Well, I was hoping for something easier to fix, thinking that you might be creating some tables on the fly ...

Comment: @Littlefoot No, all the DDL statements are to alter triggers. But you comment actually made me think about them, the transaction, and what happens depending on when and where the job fails. Its clear the DDL statements are dangerous because after one has been turned on or off, if a statement fails before its returned to normal and the rollback happens, it will remain in that state.

Comment: If there's not that much data involved, perhaps you could leave those triggers enabled all the time. They might slow things down if there are ... I don't know, *millions* of rows. Did you test it - how it behaves with triggers ON and compare it to current principle (turning them ON and OFF)?

Comment: @Littlefoot Its not that the triggers are performance issues. They are responsible for marking particular transactions. We have a bad schema, we cant edit a view. So to ensure that new records appear in the other table, another way had to be used. I wish I could correct the schema, but not allowed to. There might be away around the triggers by resorting to cursors.

Comment: Can you modify triggers, then? As they do something for "particular transactions", can you intercept them using trigger's WHEN clause so that you could leave them as they are (instead of enabling/disabling them)?

Comment: Actually, the triggers could look at a global value(s) and use that value as their on/off switch. This means I can keep using the triggers safely, and remove the DDL statements. Its a quick fix compared to rewriting everything to remove the triggers entirely. However due to the issue of commit and rollback I will be looking for other DDL statements and still pushing for the rewrite.